# What's the purpose of Javascript's Array Method valueOf?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I may get hammered for asking something overly vague, so please interpret this as a meta-programming question, as it is meant to be, and not as some sort of indirect flame war.

In trying to understand Javascript's Array a bit deeper, I ran across [this W3 reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_valueof_array.asp) for `Array.valueOf`.

It simply says:

> The valueOf() method returns the array.
>
> This method is the default method of the array object. Array.valueOf() will return the same as Array
>
> **Note**: This method will not change the original array.

---

So, I ask: what's the point?  **Is there a reason to ever use the `Array.valueOf()` method?**  Is it useful in some more complicated constructs, such as when using `call` or `apply`?  Does it help in piping together functions?  Is this simply because it creates a standard method, compared to other objects where the associated `valueOf` is more useful, and therefore help to generalize `Array` to other objects?

As far as I can tell, it is exactly identical, so I don't see its value.

Comment: Isn't `valueOf` in `Object.prototype`?

Comment: Inherited from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf ?

Comment: Lay off the W3! It's bad for you

Comment: @JayHarris that *used* to be true, last few things I've looked at there were fine.

Comment: @JaredSmith I used to believe that it wasn't true. You have to realize how in depth MDN goes with each article not to mention a polyfill for you to take home. I went back and compared an article I read today with W3's article `Array.prototype.every`. W3 claims it was added in ECMAScript edition 3. Go to the MDN website you'll see ECMAScript edition 5 instead. ;)

Comment: @JaredSmith here are the corresponding links: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_every.asp  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: @JayHarris I've found plenty of mistakes in MDN articles too. You are right that MDN articles are almost always better than their W3C counterparts, but that doesn't make W3C 'bad' to the point that I'd tell someone to avoid the site.

Comment: @JaredSmith touche. I should strongly recommend MDN instead.

Answer (score 6):

This method is inherited from [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf); every object that descends from `Object.prototype` has it. Primitive wrappers override it to return the corresponding primitive, for example, converting `new Number(5)` to `5`. The default implementation returns the object unchanged.

> JavaScript calls the valueOf method to convert an object to a primitive value. You rarely need to invoke the valueOf method yourself; JavaScript automatically invokes it when encountering an object where a primitive value is expected.

Comment: Note that you can do some [crazy things](http://2ality.com/2011/12/fake-operator-overloading.html?m=1) by hijacking `.valueOf`.

Comment: "*every object has it*" - except those like `Object.create(null)` that don't inherit from `Object.protoype` :-)